# i have problem to do curl in my hosting service (godaddy)

Tags: php, curl

i have a problem with connect to my server script. i have a economy Godaddy hosting i wrote a script in php to connect to my game server that use mavens poker appliaction . i did everything in local and its work correctly but when i put my code in godaddy host it doesnt connect i think that i have problem with curl of godaddy host. i add extension = curl.so in php.ini but it doesnt work too.

there is my script curl page

```
    <?php

   $url = "http://37.61.213.122:8087/api"; 
  $pw = "aTWdehnxuIenpiFI";                    





  function Poker_API($params)
  {
    global $url, $pw;
    $params['Password'] = $pw;
    $params['JSON'] = 'Yes';
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if (curl_errno($curl)) $obj = (object) array('Result' => 'Error', 'Error' => curl_error($curl)); 
    else if (empty($response)) $obj = (object) array('Result' => 'Error', 'Error' => 'Connection failed'); 
    else $obj = json_decode($response);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $obj;
  }

?>
```

and there is a my function that i need to do for me on the server

```
 <?php
 include('api.php') ;

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];


            function showBalance (){
                global $username;
     $params = array("Command" => "AccountsGet", "Player" => $username);
    $api = Poker_API($params);  
        echo $api-> Balance;    
            }


                        function showUsername (){
                global $username;
     $params = array("Command" => "AccountsGet", "Player" => $username);
    $api = Poker_API($params);  
        echo $api-> Player; 
            }


 function  showEmail (){
            global $username;
     $params = array("Command" => "AccountsGet", "Player" => $username);
    $api = Poker_API($params);  
        echo $api-> Email;  
 }

 function  showlastLogin (){
            global $username;
     $params = array("Command" => "AccountsGet", "Player" => $username);
    $api = Poker_API($params);  
        echo $api-> LastLogin;  
 }



 function doAccountsIncBalance ($amountinc) {
                global $username;
     $params = array("Command" => "AccountsIncBalance", "Player" => $username, "Amount" => $amountinc);
    $api = Poker_API($params);       
 }


  function doAccountsDecBalance ($amountinc) {
                global $username;
     $params = array("Command" => "AccountsDecBalance", "Player" => $username, "Amount" => $amountinc);
    $api = Poker_API($params);       
 }









?>
```

i dont know whats the problem but its work perfectly in local

Comment: Whats not working? Have you checked error logs? What debugging have you done?

Comment: it doesnt sent reqyest to the ip adress that i rquest . http://jokerpoker021.com/error_log here is error logs

Comment: i want for example for signup a new user send some information from the form to the game server but its doesnt respons at all.

Comment: logs are indicating a syntax error,did you check at that line number on that file?

Comment: i did just i have porblem for connecting to my server with curl i dont know why not acceptable

Answer (score 0):

I tested your script and it's working. Then I make a little research and from what I have found it seems that it's go Daddy hosting problem. So you better right them and ask how to make your script work or find a more reliable hosting.

Comment: for these 2 function that doesnt have any return because i need to do this once it send json respond to the game server and they are for increase and decrase the balance of the player

Comment: Show also your public_html/test.php

Comment: here is the test.php its to simple just want to use fuction that should echo balance result or something else
`<?php

include ('server.php');
include ('connectdatabase.php');


showBalance ();



 ?> `

Comment: its doesnt work it should show balance of account from server but doesnt connect to show balance at all!

Comment: Where from do you now that the reason in the connection? It shows you blank, prints error to your log?

Comment: the error_log is free nothing there. look i have a mavens poker application on the windows server i wrote a script to register and do some function of my gamer profile. i test the script its work on my local laptop and with these curl code that i wrote and functions its add player to my game server , show their balance and ect. but when i put my script on the my host it doesnt work just the part that need information from my game server . so i think that the curl have a problem another part work correctly

Comment: error is `Failed to connect to 37.61.213.122 port 8087: Connection refused `